# k3s - Can't access my service based on service name

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have created a service like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: amen-sc
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3030
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    component: scc-worker
```

I am able to access this service, from within my pods of the same cluster (& Namespace), using the IP address I get from `kubectl get svc`, but I am not able to access using the service name like `curl amen-sc:3030`.

Please advise what could possibly be wrong.
I intend to expose certain pods, only within my cluster and access them using the `service-name:port` format.

Comment: Make sure you have `kube-dns` service running with `kubectl get service kube-dns -n kube-system`

Comment: @p10l Ok I think that is the problem. The kube-dns service is working, however, in K3S it works upon a coredns pod, which is not working. Let me see what is wrong with it.

Comment: @p10l Yes that is the problem, please make it as answer so that I can accpet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have DNS service configured and corresponding pods are running.

```text
kubectl get svc -n kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
```

and

```text
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
```